# h2database login screen not working in my spring application

Tags: spring, hibernate, h2

I am using h2dabase as in memory database in my application. 
I have added following dependency in my pom.xml file.

```html
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>   
</dependency>
```

Following is my application.properties

```js
spring.application.name=currency-exchange-service 
server.port=8000 
spring.jpa.show-sql=true 
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
```

Following is the error I am getting on the browser:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To reproduce the error, I've downloaded a fresh [Spring boot](https://start.spring.io/) project with the `spring-boot-starter-web` and `h2` modules. When using your settings, the URL was inaccessible just like your screenshot showed.

The URL did became accessible when I added 
`spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console` to `application.properties`.

Comment: Your `application.properties` file doesn't have the property `spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console`.

Comment: I added still the same issue.